# Claiming Season set gear on a season alt

Tags: diablo-iii

I have completed Season 21 on a Necromancer and gotten to 4/10 in Slayer on the Season Journey. I got my 6 pieces of set gear on the main, via the mail as per usual.

I then re-birthed a Monk as a season alt, and he's now 70. In the Season Journey screen it tells me that I have unlocked the set pieces, and they have been added to my collection.

Are the Monk season 21 set pieces in a super secret hidden place where I can just go and collect them? Or is there a bug in the Season Journey screen where if you roll a season alt and get to 70 it will always show that class' season gear as unlocked?

Image below shows the Season Journey page for the Monk alt.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Season Journey is shared across your account. Haedrig's Gift can only be claimed once per season, not once per seasonal character. It wouldn't personally call this a "bug" per se; I'd call it a design oversight, but that could be argued either way. Regardless, the UI could be more explicit, and is arguably lying to you in this case.

Comment: OK, so if I didn't collect it from my Necromancer, rolled an alt and got that to 70, I could have then collected the mail and got the Monk set pieces instead... that's not what it says, but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: @spikey_richie if you read the text, you can see that it talks about armor and not about specific set pieces. Since you collected all armor pieces on the necromancer, it is correct to show them as claimed, even though the set pieces are not what you collected

Comment: Hardcore characters have separate stash and [paragon](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/1kyvo0/hardcoresoftcore_paragon_levels_separate/) and can't trade with normal ones, but still, it's [one goddammit set of gift](https://www.reddit.com/r/diablo3/comments/6xp8q1/can_you_not_claim_haedrigs_gift_in_softcore_and/) per season. Just adds to how Blizzard cares about Diablo3.

Comment: I'm not running a hardcore. It's just 2 season 21 characters.